# JPA order by with xml field content

Tags: xml, jpa, sql-order-by

I have a table (Country) with idCountry and name columns.
Name column contains xml data with locale translations like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <root available-locales="es_ES,ca_ES" default-locale="es_ES"> <Name language-id="ca_ES">Espanya</Name> <Name language-id="es_ES">España</Name></root>
```

I need to order data by name, but not for the full xml content but for a concrete locale data.

Is posible to do this with a NameQuery?

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = CountryEntity.TABLE_NAME)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = CountryEntity.GET_ALLDATA_QUERY_NAME, query =         CountryEntity.GET_ALLDATA_QUERY, hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable",   value = "true")})})
public class CountryEntity {

/* TABLE */
protected static final String TABLE_NAME = "EP_COUNTRY";

/* COLUMNS */
public static final String ID_COUNTRY_COLUMN = "ID_COUNTRY";
public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "NAME";

public static final String GET_ALLDATA_QUERY = "SELECT c FROM CountryEntity c ";

private Long idCountry;
private String name;

@Column(name = ID_COUNTRY_COLUMN, nullable = false, updatable = false)
@Id
public Long getIdCountry() {
    return idCountry;
}

@Transient
public String getName(String locale) {
    return Localization.getLocalization(this.getNames(), locale);
}

@Lob
@Column(name = NAME_COLUMN, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
public String getNames() {
    return name;
}
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to parse XML with a Named Query.

Why not store your data as regular columns (locale, name, etc) and generate the XML on the fly when you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!!

The xml is not need at all. Is was an idea to store data using only one column.

If i store data as regular columns i'll need a column for every locale available in my application and adding a new locale would suppose modify all tables of this type; i think this is not a good idea.
Another approach that can be evaluated is with a related table (1-n) with locale translations.
In this case i think i could have a namedquery with a join, a parameter to filter locale and order by column name as a regular column